# Variance of independence test - coin package

Tags: r, variance, independence, permutation-test

I'm using the independence test of the package `coin`. 
independence_test provides a general independence test for two sets of variables measured on arbitrary scales. This function is based on the general framework for conditional inference procedures proposed by Strasser and Weber (1999). The salient parts of the Strasser-Weber framework are elucidated by Hothorn et al. (2006) and a thorough description of the software implementation is given by Hothorn et al. (2008).
The null hypothesis of independence, or conditional independence given block, between y1, . . . , yq and x1, ..., xp is tested.

Here's a simple example:

```
x=c(2,5,10) 
y=c(1,7,9)
test=data.frame(cbind(x,y))
w<-rep(1,length(y))

c<-independence_test(y~x, data = test) 

statistic(c,type = c("test")) #Z = 1.2888
expectation(c) #96.33333
variance(c) #566.2222
```

I can compute the expectation with:

```
mean=(sum(x)*sum(y))/length(y)
```

but I don't know how to compute the variance (Sigma_j below).

Here the test statistic:

[image]

and the mean and variance/covariance matrix:
[image]

Comment: Could you please *describe* the test that this software is performing?  As it is, since the code you posted reveals nothing about the algorithm, you are obliging interested readers to research the `coin` package--but surely that's something you have done, so please be so kind as to share that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example you have provided, both transformations are just the identity, i.e., $h(Y_i) = Y_i$ and $g(X_{ji}) = X_{ji}$. Also, the weights are all equal to 1 and thus the sum of the weights $w_{.}$ is simply the sample size. Finally, all the matrix multiplications, Kronecker producs, etc. just become simple scalar products. The statistic is then essentially a simple Pearson correlation statistic.

```
T <- sum(x * y)             ## statistic
E <- mean(y)                ## expectiation of h(Y)
V <- mean((y - E)^2)        ## variance of h(Y)
mu <- sum(x) * E            ## expectation of T
w. <- length(y)             ## sum of weights (here: number of observations)
Sigma <- w. / (w. - 1) * V * sum(x^2) -
  1/(w. - 1) * V * sum(x)^2 ## variance of T
z <- (T - mu) / sqrt(Sigma) ## standardized statistic
```

And this then yields the intermediate results and final statistic you quote above:

```
c("expectation" = mu, "variance" = Sigma, "standardized" = z)
##  expectation     variance standardized 
##    96.333333   566.222222     1.288763
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! My mistake was in the computation of V.

Comment: @JulsFlor You're very welcome. If this solved your question, please also accept it so that it appears correspondingly here on SE.